# Saving table from PostgreSQL to MapInfo File?

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr

I have two tables: 
1 with geometry in WGS
2 with geometry in Local System

I tried this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo File" output2.tab PG:"host=localhost user=postgres password=123456 dbname=postgis" -sql "SELECT * from filedata WHERE num=1"
```

and get files.  However, after I open the files in QGIS, I see that file from the table in WGS coordinates is correct but the file from the table in the local system has a shift.

WGS

[image]

Local system

[image]

The upper part of the polygons are different but its ok.

I add proj line to file `GDAL\projlib\epsg` but it did not help. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try with the -s_srs/-a_srs/-t_srs options?

Comment: Please ask your second question on a another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the -a_srs attribute with your projection. There is also an issue with bounds in the gdal driver for the Mapinfo tab format which may be related. For more information refer to the [documentation](https://www.gdal.org/drv_mitab.html).